# Ember Deprecation: lookupFactory was called on a registry

Tags: javascript, ember.js, deprecation-warning

I just installed a fresh version of ember-cli. I did an `ember g my_project` and then `ember s`. I have a couple of deprecations out of the box:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.0
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.18
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
ember.debug.js:4888DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:4954DEPRECATION: `lookupFactory` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API no longer receives a container, and you should use an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers for more details.
        at Object.Registry.lookupFactory (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12183:26)
        at ember$data$lib$initializers$store$$initializeStore (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70659:48)
        at Object.ember$data$lib$setup$container$$setupContainer [as initialize] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70969:7)
        at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14662:23
        at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14685:9
        at visit (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12701:7)
        at visit (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12699:9)
        at DAG.topsort (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12813:11)
        at Namespace.default.extend._runInitializer (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14684:13)
ember.debug.js:4954DEPRECATION: `lookup` was called on a Registry. The `initializer` API no longer receives a container, and you should use an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations#toc_deprecate-access-to-instances-in-initializers for more details.
        at Object.Registry.lookup (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12173:26)
        at ember$data$lib$initializers$store$$initializeStore (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70677:28)
        at Object.ember$data$lib$setup$container$$setupContainer [as initialize] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70969:7)
        at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14662:23
        at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14685:9
        at visit (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12701:7)
        at visit (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12699:9)
        at DAG.topsort (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12813:11)
        at Namespace.default.extend._runInitializer (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14684:13)
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1 [Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK_hcA04='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

Also, I have a bunch of Report Only warnings:

```
[Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK_hcA04='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

How can I "correctly" fix these warnings on a fresh app from ember-cli?

Comment: Have you added anything to your project, or is this all after the initial setup of Ember CLI?

Comment: Try running this from your project directory:

`$ rm -rf node_modules/ bower_components/`
`$ npm cache clean`
`$ bower cache clean`
`$ npm install && bower install`

Comment: @JonKoops -- Thanks. However, that did not clear it up. Same result. It was a brand new empty project with no changes. I just wanted to repro the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The `lookupFactory` deprecations are because Ember Data hasn't been updated yet to use the new API. You should ignore these deprecations, they will be solved in the next version of Ember Data. As for the CSP errors I have no idea where they are coming from, but make sure you're using the latest Ember CLI version. If you still have issues after that consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep poking away at it.